# Is this sentence grammatically correct? The park is a space for people to play

Tags: prepositions

I know it is right to say: The game is fun to play. (Because we can say *play the game*)

I know it is right to say: The park is a space for people to play **in**. (Because we can say *play **in** the park*)

I am less certain about: The park is a space for people to play. (Because we cannot say *play the park*)

Comment: It's the same construction as "The disco is a place for people to dance." They are not dancing the disco, they are just dancing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The park is a space for people to play.*

In speech, it’s likely that no awkwardness would be detected from hearing this sentence, especially if the context for using it is clear. On a test, it would depend on the course material that is being evaluated, but one typically plays *in a park*. This the most likely distinction one would encounter in an ELL classroom, as such, the sentence that uses *to play in* is probably the best choice in circumstances that describe the practical act of *playing*.

However, the sentence, as written, can be interpreted, with some semantical gymnastics, as an existential, philosophical statement. Such as:

- *The park is a space (meant) for people to (use for) play.*

The elided words serve to guide the reader’s interpretation. If written out with intent, *(meant)* combines with the ethereal nature of *space* to set this existential statement into a philosophical realm that tends to preclude a practical interpretation of what follows. Similarly, *to (use for) play* splits the infinitive to isolate its base form to emphasize that the infinitive *to play* can also represent *play* as a concept rather than a practical action.

From my head:

> The angry man climbed the base of the statue to address the milling
> crowd. “*The park is a space for people to play*. We must not condone the presence
> of rag-tag drug peddlers that threaten the safety
> of our children with their seedy business!”